# Why can't play music at reboot?

Tags: bash, cron, mplayer

`OS` info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to play music at reboot.

```
sudo crontab -e
@reboot /usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3
```

No music play ,check cron log to see what happened:

```
sudo journalctl -u cron | grep -e "root" |grep  -e mplayer -A 3
Oct 17 20:07:46 debian CRON[633]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3)
Oct 17 20:11:07 debian CRON[593]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

The cmd in crontab starts at Oct 17 20:07:46,closed the session at Oct 17 20:11:07,almost 200seconds!

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 20, 7, 46)
end  = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 20, 11, 7)
end-start
datetime.timedelta(seconds=201)
```

It means that `/usr/bin/sleep 200` executed ,but `/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3` never start ,why?

Without `/usr/bin/sleep 200` in crontab,the `/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3` only last 7 seconds!It is a 5 minutes long music!

```
Oct 17 20:04:50 debian CRON[632]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3)
Oct 17 20:04:57 debian CRON[590]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Update to create cron with a regular user,the same log :

```
Oct 17 21:37:26 debian CRON[638]: (debian) CMD (/usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mplayer /home/debian/welcome.mp3)
Oct 17 21:40:48 debian CRON[593]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user debian
```

Same action ,from start to end ,it last 202 seconds,almost 200 seconds.
Update for adding a mplayer's log.

```
Oct 17 22:25:11 debian CRON[646]: (debian) CMD (/usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3  2>/tmp/mplayer.reboot.log)
Oct 17 22:28:33 debian CRON[593]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user debian

cat /tmp/mplayer.reboot.log
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm_hw.c:1715:(snd_pcm_hw_open) open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2): No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: No such file or directory
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
[AO SDL] Unable to open audio: No available audio device
Failed to initialize audio driver 'sdl:aalib'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
```

Check the file:

```
file  /home/debian/welcome.mp3
/home/debian/welcome.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 64 kbps, 48 kHz, Stereo
```

THe playback hardware devices:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC662 rev3 Digital [ALC662 rev3 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Why are you doing this as root? You log in using a non-root user, right? So what happens if you add this to the regular user's crontab? Just run `crontab -e` instead of `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: Please try on your linux and paste your result,no matter which linux distro  is.

Comment: Argh! Sorry, I hadn't realized you already tried and updated the question! OK, so it isn't a permissions issue. Can you please change the cron line to run this command: `/usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mplayer  /home/debian/welcome.mp3  2>/tmp/mplayer.reboot.log` and then see if the `/tmp/mplayer.reboot.log` file is created and if there is anything in it.

Comment: Neither pulse or alsa initialized when mplayer tries to playback. I suggest to run it from systemd service with proprerly configured dependencies.

Comment: Could you try `aplay -l`?  What result do you get?

Comment: It is working from crontab at any specified time?

Comment: After logging my desktop ,i can play music with mplayer or any other music player,how to make it working at the reboot?

Comment: @showkey an incredibly, incredibly, good question. I don't know how bounties work but if the bounty expires and the question as well - can you ask it again? if the question does not expire after the bounty expires - then all is good;

I would like to see the answer to this question so I Will try some stuff;
have it great!

Answer (score 1):

### What goes wrong

By Debian's default settings, a normal user has permission to use audio devices *only when logged in locally*. Commands executed from crontab are not part of a login session, and so cron jobs will not automatically get permission to use audio devices.

This is the primary reason why `@reboot` cron jobs running as a regular user will fail to play audio by default, even if you use a fully non-interactive player utility.

The secondary reason would be that most audio applications are configured to use PulseAudio, which allows e.g. switching audio output from one sound chip to another while audio is playing. But PulseAudio is a user session service: it is not running when nobody is logged in. So your `mplayer` is falling back to plain ALSA, which then runs into having no permissions, as mentioned above.

Also, since normally PulseAudio is used for output selection, in this case you would have to specify the output in ALSA-specific way since PulseAudio will not be involved.

Currently your `mplayer` defaults to attempting to use the first playback device of the first ALSA sound card (`/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p`) which does not seem to exist on your system: your actual first ALSA playback device seems to be `/dev/snd/pcmC0D3p`, which is the audio output associated with your HDMI 0 display interface, rather than the motherboard's analog audio output, which would be `/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p`. If you have no display connected to HDMI 0, or if it is not audio output capable, this would also cause the attempt to use this device to immediately fail. This might explain why your attempt to play audio as root fails too.

### How to fix

The `base-passwd` documentation file `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz` says:

> audio
>
> This group can be used locally to give a set of users access to an audio device.

So, since you would want the `debian` user to be capable of using audio devices *at any time*, not just when logged in locally, you should add the user to the `audio` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio debian
```

That should allow you to use a regular user's crontab for this task, so you wouldn't need to use root's crontab for this. (Also allows you to kill the audio player as yourself without using sudo once logged in, if you need to silence the music for some reason!)

Then you would need to add some options to your crontabbed `mplayer` command (if you really want to have the overkill of using a *video player* to play audio):

```
@reboot /usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mplayer -noconsolecontrols -ao alsa:device=hw=2.0 /home/debian/welcome.mp3
```

For crontab use, I'd consider using some more lightweight audio player instead, e.g. `mpg321`:

```
@reboot usr/bin/sleep 200;/usr/bin/mpg321 -q -o alsa -a hw:2,0 /home/debian/welcome.mp3
```

If you want to eliminate the `sleep 200` part, you could add an ordering dependency to `cron.service`:

```
sudo systemctl edit cron.service
```

... then type in the following lines and save the file:

```
[Unit]
After=alsa-restore.service
```

This will add an override file as `/etc/systemd/system/cron.service.d/override.conf`, containing the lines you typed. Those lines will ensure `crond` will only start after `alsa-restore.service` (an "oneshot" service) has been executed, which means all the sound drivers have been loaded and system default audio mixer levels have been set. Now there should be no possibility of `crond` starting before the audio subsystem is ready.

Answer (score -1):

You have two problems. On the first hand, you should not use *lirc*, as clearly shown by your log:

```
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
```

To correct this, create the file (and directory, if it does not exist yet) *$HOME/.mplayer/config* with the line

```
lirc=no
```

The second problem is that, if you have not logged in to your graphical session (X11, presumably for you, but I also use Wayland), then your mplayer cannot possibly work: how can it open its console if you still have not initialized your graphical environment?

On the other hand, it seems to me to make more sense to wish the music to be played at (graphical!) login, rather than at boot. Thus my suggestion is that you create an autostart script in *$HOME/.config/autostart* (works on my KDE, may differ according to your DE), with content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=mpl
Exec=bash -c 'sleep 3 && /usr/bin/mplayer  -noconsolecontrols "/home/mario/Videos/Two Steps From Hell - Heart of Courage.m4a" 2>/tmp/mplayer.reboot.log'
Terminal=false
Icon=mplayer
Comment=Just show indicator
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

The only thing of notice above is the option *-noconsolecontrols*, which is [necessary in order to run *mplayer* in the background](https://superuser.com/a/366119/255732). This works just fine on an Ubuntu 22.04 KDE run-of-the-mill install.

.